# Understanding python imports work and why successful imports in pylint depend on directory I run pylint from

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

I have some code with this (simplified) structure

```
proj:
  rendering:
    renderers
    etc
 commands
   task1.py
   task2.py
   etc
```

I was doing an overhaul of rendering and so had to import stuff from renderers in various places.  I let pycharm create the import command when I needed something to import and didn't think much about them otherwise, it all ran for me and my tests all passed locally.  Then I checked it in and it failed our bamboo builds.  Turns out this command:

```
pylint --errors-only <project_dir>
```

will fail with a bunch of unable to import errors  but if I cd into project and run

```
pylint --errors-only .
```

it works fine.

Looking at the failed imports they are all referencing to things I created in rendering.  so for example this line was failing:

```
from rendering.renderers import ListRenderer
```

That line existd, and failed, in both renderers/**init**.py file and the tasks/task1.py.  If I just change that to add my project name in front it's fine, so

```
from <project>/rendering.renderers import ListRenderer
```

So I have a fix for this problem already, yay!  But this all suggests I don't understand the python importing logic because I don't understand how the importing was working in the first place.

redering.renderers doesn't seem like a valid relative import from within my task1.py module, I would expect to need something more like "../rendering/renderers" instead; so I'm not sure how the import pycharm put in worked, how was I successfully finding the right line to run?.  I also don't understand why pylint worked from within the project directory but failed when I made the call from the parent directory, though I imagine if I understood the first I'd understand the second?

Anyone able to explain to me how I broke my bamboo build? :)